# Wordpress template_directory functions ignore self signed SSL

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

**EDIT -
It looks like the cause of the problem was the wordpress HTTPS plugin. If I disable that it works as expected.**

All style and script paths are served using the wordpress methods `get_template_directory_uri()` or relevant equivalent. The [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) are pretty clear in the first line:

> Retrieve template directory URI for the current theme. Checks for SSL.

However, using a self signed SSL this still returns the http path, which of course causes all css and js to fail.

We're including like so:

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/lib/bootstrap-custom.js"></script>
```

Does anyone know if there is a workaround that does not require altering every instance where we call `get_template_directory_uri()` or is this just because the SSL identity is not verified that the function fails to use https?

We used the self signed SSL hoping we could run a quick transaction test with Authorize.net (which may not like self signed SSL anyhow) so we wouldn't have to buy an actual SSL for a test that may take 2 minutes to verify. So much for shortcuts, huh? Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to dig down a bit to find this, but what it's doing is checking to see if the current request that's being processed is using SSL.

Basically, the is_ssl() function is as follows:

```
function is_ssl() {
    if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ) {
        if ( 'on' == strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) )
            return true;
        if ( '1' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'] )
            return true;
    } elseif ( isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) && ( '443' == $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So, are you hitting this code with an https request?

Comment: That was my first attempt. But server port is returning 80, server protocol is returning http/1.1 - so whatever is intending to detect the self signed SSL is not accepting it, despite it allowing the page to be served via https with the standard untrusted warning.

Comment: Is the server Apache? Is it behind a proxy of some kind that's doing the SSL for you and then making http calls to the actual server?

Comment: It is apache. And there is no proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Check how WooCommerce forces SLL on `template_directory_uri` and `stylesheet_directory_uri`:

https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-https.php#L23

Comment: That looks like it's just forcing under a certain condition, which I could probably do with is_page just to hack it. Problem is, https is working, but it is not being seen as https. So the conventional methods for detecting https are not working. I was looking for maybe a php option for forcing validation generically.